# SharePoint 2013: Forced to have an App tile? Or Re-design?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, best-practices, design

Do anyone know of a way to hide an app tile, it appears that we are forced to have one with each app we install?

For example,

I just want to deploy a Remote Event Receiver to a site.

1. Create a provider hosted SharePoint App.
2. Add a remote event receiver.
3. Add a App installed event to register the remote event receiver to a list on the host web.
4. Profit?

Now.. seems to work, but my user a now wondering why there is a big blue tile that links to a page with pointless info on it.

So if there an easy way to hide this tile form the users? I don't feel deploying some CSS with some gnarly selector like `$(".tiles:contains(RemoteEventReceiverApp)").hide()` is going to cut it.

*Note: I was tempted to outline the purpose of the app on the tile page, but really is no concern to the users*.

If not, is this a design fail and bad practice... should the receiver be registered by a deploy script via CSOM?

Answer (score -1):

This is to remove the logo and the name:

```
#s4-titlerow{
    display:none!important;
}
```

This is to remove the top bar (newsfeed,...):

```
div#suiteBar {
    display: none;
}
```

This is to remove the gray bar (browse):

```
#s4-ribbonrow{ 
    display:none !important; 
}
```

Add these to your .CSS file

Comment: Sorry this is not what what I asked, none of the above CSS will hide a specific app tile. I will edit the question to be more clear.